# Database inserting error in recess framework

Tags: php, database, recess

I just don't know how to solve the problem below:

I have an API made with recess framework, and everything works fine, until I set the `RecessConf::$mode = RecessConf::PRODUCTION`.

The problem:
In PRODUCTION mode my DB inserts are not working well.
I use this code for inserting:

For requests:

```
$sessionData = new SessionData();
$sessionData->parent_id = NULL;
$sessionData->request_id = 1234567;
$sessionData->request_click_id = asld1212312llkn1212;
$sessionData->request_name = 'myRequestName';
$sessionData->ip_address = NULL;
$sessionData->save();
$ID = $sessionData->id;
```

Then:

```
$user = new User();
$user->session_data_id = $ID;
$user->session_request_id = 1234567;
$user->data = json_encode( ['name' => 'Test', 'email' => 'e@mail.com'] );
$user->save();
```

Then:

This is for response (please note the parent_id should be the same as the ID from the first query):

```
$sessionData = new SessionData();
$sessionData->parent_id = $ID;
$sessionData->request_id = 78901234;
$sessionData->request_click_id = xy.cmy.qp1212121;
$sessionData->request_name = 'myResponeName';
$sessionData->ip_address = NULL;
$sessionData->save();
```

And the `$sessionData->parent_id` is totally random. Sometimes it appears in the database but in most times not.
I'm sure I have the `$ID` because if I am dumping it I can see, and if I am trying to insert a fix number, like

```
$sessionData->parent_id = 123;
```

it is still totally random.

But in DEVELOPMENT mode everything works as expected.

Thanks in advance,

Scheme for `session_data` table:

```
CREATE TABLE `session_data` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `parent_id` varchar(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `request_id` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `request_click_id` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `request_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `ip_address` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Scheme for user table:

```
CREATE TABLE `user` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `session_data_id` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `session_request_id` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ip_address` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `data` text,
  `created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: Please show us your database scheme

Comment: I edit my prev question for better view, thanks!

Comment: $sessionData->request_click_id = xy.cmy.qp1212121; - Is this a string? Then quote it. Same with $sessionData->request_id. In you scheme they are both varchars, so please quote them.

Comment: Tried, but unfortunately it's still the same....